# Hibernate: interesting quiz with insertable=false & updatable=false

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

***What I have:***

Multiple `Owner` entities which hold one of `Client` subtype entities. I need that each subtype of Client entity can be saved to database only once, so I use `insertable = false, updatable = false`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    //getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class AngryClient extends Client {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class SilentClient extends Client {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "_vacancy")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)

     //getters & setters
}
```

***What I can't grasp:***

Due to `insertable = false, updatable = false`, when we save the owner, *the client won't be saved*. It can be easely be checked in database. The *only column that is stored in `owner` table is `id`*.

**So how does Hibernate know which `Client` corresponds to which `Owner`?!**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Owner owner1 = new Owner();
Owner owner2 = new Owner();
Client client1 = new AngryClient();
Client client2 = new SilentClient();
owner1.setClient(client1);
owner2.setClient(client2);
session.save(owner1); //client1 isn't saved
session.save(owner2); //client2 isn't saved
int owner1Id = owner1.getId();
session.getTransaction().commit(); //client table is empty

Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
Owner owner = (Owner) session1.get(Owner.class, owner1Id);
System.out.println(owner.getClient());  //HOW DOES IT WORK?! (owner.getClient() returns me AngryClient)
```

***Question:***

How does it work? Or how Hibernate fill up the client filed when we do `session.get(Owner.class, owner1Id)`?

Comment: sorry, make mistake in `session1.get(Owner.class, owner1Id)` (I used session instead of session1). Close this question please

Comment: you can close the question yourself, click the `close` button

Comment: I've already vote to close this question. But as I understand it is needed five votes.

Comment: weird, I can normally delete my own posts